# 301 redirect to new domain

Tags: redirect, seo

I need the 301 code for redirect old domain to new one with all pages and folders.

Seems like I can't find it anywhere.

Also if I use the 301 redirect, am I gonna lose my keywords rankings or position for doing that.

(I mean moving from **3 yrs old domain** to *2 days old domain*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in an .htaccess file in your root web directory:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Your rankings will fluctuate ate first as the transition is never smooth. But in the end your rankings *should* return to normal.